# extract data in mysql from the string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run mysql query to get the part of string below is string stored in database

```
nb=5&pfid=2098&rssurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffeeds.feedburner.com%2Ffoxnews%2Flatest&nb=5
```

using mysql query i need to extract the pfid which is '2098' and insert it into other table field. i tried few queries but i am not able to achieve it.

anybody have idea how to do this may be mysql expert...or sql query expert.

thank you in advance

regards,
mona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `instr` and `substring`:

```
select left(val, instr(val, '&')-1) 
from (
  select substring(col,instr(col, 'pfid=')+5,length(col)) val
  from yourtable
  ) t
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d973/1)

This does assume the string value will contain an `&` after the value.  If not, you could include a little additional logic to check.

In regards to inserting that value into another field, should be fairly straight-forward now that you have the value. Depends on your exact needs.

Comment: Man Sgeddes you are simply great.. spot on answer.. thank you very much.. you saved my lot of time.. have good night(AU)